# HTTPClient - MVC: How to add multiple header?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpclient

I try add another header but error when request from API
Please help me how to add another header to httpclient without error?

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-protobuf"));
                if(authvalue != null && authvalue.Length > 0)
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-authvalue", authvalue);
```

it's not passed action in API

Answer (score 0):

Try use `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AddWithoutValidation("x-authvalue", authvalue);`

more info checkout https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204926(v=vs.110)

Comment: Thank you for response, but it's same result with "httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-authvalue", authvalue);" 
after add custom header, request not access to action in API, if i clear this line, it's work fine

Comment: just for clarification, when you say `request not access to action in API` you mean by `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AddWithoutValidation("x-authvalue", authvalue);` there is no error but wasn't added to the header or you mean there was a runtime exception (error)

Comment: it's added into header request and i can see it in headerstore data
1. It passed in AuthorizeAttribute : CustomAuthorizeAttb
2. Request is not call Aaction cua API (Initial, always return error 500)

[CustomAuthorizeAttb]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
 public async Task<List<ProductVM>> Initial(string id){...}
}

Comment: so if I understand correctly, your original problem of adding to header have been solved (since it appear in the header data), you are having problem at receiving end (server) right?  If so, then it would be another question, since we will need detail of how your server end is doing with the header